# WYSIWYG Image Upload in Basic Page (CKEditor and CKFinder)

Tags: media, wysiwyg, files

I was able to use CKEditor and CKFinder to add in-body image upload capability for article nodes.
However, the functionality was not transferred to basic page nodes.
What do I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it looks like you can upload nodes to your basic page, but they're not displaying then you're probably using filtered HTML as your page filter. If you don't have the ability to add pictures at all, then look at the configuration of CKEditor and you may need to add the appropriate button for the content type.

Comment: Gah! You are absolutely right about the filtered HTML vs. full HTML. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to mark as answered so others can find it.